# Error: Could not find or load main class com.spring.solarlog.netflixeurekanamingserver.NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am getting an error when I am trying to run Eureka naming server. Please find my code below:

```java
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableEurekaServer // Enabling eureka naming server
public class NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) { // main class
        SpringApplication.run(NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Pom.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.spring.solarlog</groupId>
<artifactId>netflix-eureka-naming-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>netflix-eureka-naming-server</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> // have added the server maven dependencies
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version> // have added the server maven dependencies
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.spring.solarlog.netflixeurekanamingserver.NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.spring.solarlog.netflixeurekanamingserver.NetflixEurekaNamingServerApplication
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps for **Standing up a Eureka Service Registry** on Spring official website ([link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/))? Maybe you should check your dependencies.

Comment: When I am adding the dependencies as:<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> // have added the server maven dependencies
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version> // have added the server maven dependencies
    </dependency> I am able to to see the load main class error

Comment: However when I am adding the dependencies as: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
  </dependency> I am able to see the error as: EnableEurekaServer cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I used your pom.xml and removed the version of `<artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId> ` with my configuration file, the application started without any error.

Comment: I have no idea about `com.spring.solarlog`, but version 1.1.6 of spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server is not compatible with boot 2.1 and Greenwich.RELEASE. You shouldn't need the version there.

Comment: @spencergibb: com.spring.solarlog is my package. If I am not specifying the version  I am unable to import the jar required for annotation EnableEurekaServer and this is throwing an error. If you can suggest me to fix this then it would be great.

Comment: `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server` is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

I set up sutable JDK to the module in Project Structure, in this way: Project Structure -> Modules -> {Click on Special Module} -> Right tab, SDK module list - Select the appropriate SDK in use.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: I guess you can explain it more to get a good clarity on your answer.

Comment: Project Structure -> Modules -> {Click on the specific module} -> Right tab, list Module SDK -> select proper SDK in use.

Comment: That's great. Please update this in your answer (That's what actually I mean in my prev comment)

Comment: Well, I haven't tried. Interestingly, I (we) used to add these comments when a new user arrives in stackoverflow (we get notified of your first answer/question/post/comment etc). Anyways thank you for updating. Happy stackoverflow days :) Keep posting more.